# How to get the selected item from List

Tags: python, list, traitsui

Key code:

```
points = List([], editor=ListStrEditor(editable=False, multi_select=False))
```

How can I get the selected Items?
Is there an attribute of points, so I can easily get the selected item
List:
[image: List]

Comment: please do not link images to one or two lines - add them in the question

Comment: Inline image; removed tags from title; grammar; noise reduction; layout.